# appearance of virtual-mailboxes description in neomutt sidebar

Tags: neomutt, notmuch

I began this question because I couldn't find an answer, but then I looked into closed issues at `neomutt` and found a fix, which is simple, but as it hasn't yet propagated into neomutt's documentation, I'm still posting this question, along with the answer.

These are my relevant `neomutt` configuration settings for one of my email accounts:

```
# Sidebar mappings
set sidebar_visible = yes
set sidebar_width = 22
set sidebar_short_path = yes
set sidebar_next_new_wrap = yes
set mail_check_stats
set sidebar_format = '%B%?F? [%F]?%* %?N?%N/? %?S?%S?'
bind index,pager B sidebar-toggle-visible

# mailboxes
set folder = "/home/jo/.local/share/mail/live"
mailboxes "=Archive" "=Deleted" "=Drafts" "=INBOX" "=Junk" "=Sent" "=Waiting"
virtual-mailboxes "All" "notmuch://?query=tag:live"
macro index,pager gl "<change-vfolder>All<enter>" "go to All"
virtual-mailboxes "Aude" "notmuch://?query=Aude"  # this line is temporarily added as an additional test
```

Up until about several weeks ago, my `neomutt` `sidebar` would look like this:

```
Archive           491│
Deleted             3│
Drafts               │
INBOX            8/ 9│
Junk                 │
Sent                 │
Waiting             1│
All            9/ 565│
```

But that last line, the "All" `definition` now appears like this (with the temporary "Aude" test coming after it):

```
query=tag:live 9/ 565│
query=Aude     1/ 251│
```

You can see that the `definition`, "All", or the test case "Aude" is now not showing, but is replaced by what comes after `notmuch://?` in my configuration. My macro `gl` still works, showing me the contents of my virtual mailbox "All".

I seem to be still following exactly [Notmuch Feature](https://neomutt.org/feature/notmuch)

> 6 Commands
> `virtual-mailboxes description notmuch-URI { description notmuch-URI ...}`
> `unvirtual-mailboxes{ * | mailbox ... }`
> `virtual-mailboxes` is like the `mailboxes` command, except that it takes a description. The mailbox will be watched for new mail and will appear in the sidebar.

So there seems to've been, several weeks ago, some change in neomutt's that's broken this functionality, or else I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4):

An incomplete but adequate fix is described here [Version 20200814 virtual mailbox names in sidebar are showing the query strings instead of the names #2595](https://github.com/neomutt/neomutt/issues/2595). In my case, I've just changed `%B` to `%D` in my [Sidebar Format String](https://neomutt.org/guide/gettingstarted.html#intro-sidebar-format).

Comment: Now that is what I call a real lifesaver :)